# Как получить промежуточные точки из проложенного маршрута гугл мапс?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api

Есть в гугл карте маршрут от точки А до точки Б. Есть ли возможность получить координаты точек каждых 100 метров из этого маршрута?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Маршрут - это polyline, массив отрезков. У каждого отрезка есть координаты начала и конца.

[Функции навигации](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry?hl=ru#Navigation):

> Если известны угол направления, исходная точка и расстояние пути (в метрах), координаты назначения можно рассчитать с помощью метода computeOffset().

и

> Угол направления для двух точек можно рассчитать с помощью метода computeHeading(), передав ему два объекта LatLng с координатами from (исходная точка) и to (точка назначения).

Т.е., есть две точки (начало отрезка, конец отрезка), угол направления для них вычисляем с помощью computeHeading, а расстояние от начала отрезка до точки, находящейся от него на расстоянии 100 метров - с помощью computeOffset.